# Attribute "type" must be declared for element "forward" exception.. What it is about..?? what changes do we have to make..?

Tags: java, exception, struts, struts-config

whenever i launch the webapplication, i get the following exception..
what changes do we have to make..?? do we have to add type attribute to the forward tag of struts-config.xml.. ?? if so, what values the type attribute possibly take ?

```
SEVERE: Parse Error at line 23 column 67: Attribute "type" must be declared for element    type "forward".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/TilesStruts/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 67; Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "forward".
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1253)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1917)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:763)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1827)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:740)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:689)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:356)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Added struts_config.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
      "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">


<struts-config>
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="EmployeeForm" type="com.myapp.example.EmployeeForm"/>

</form-beans>

<global-exceptions>

</global-exceptions>

<global-forwards>
    <forward name="welcome"  path="/Welcome.do"/>
</global-forwards>

<action-mappings>
    <action input="/testListener.jsp" name="EmployeeForm"
       parameter="method"     path="/EmployeeAction" scope="session" type="com.myapp.example.EmployeeAction">
       <!--parameter is request parameter name-->
        <forward name="success" path="/success.jsp"  />
    <forward name="failure" path="/failure.jsp" />
    </action>
    <action path="/Welcome" forward="/testListener.jsp"/>
</action-mappings>

<controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor"/>

<message-resources parameter="com/myapp/struts/ApplicationResource"/>    

<!-- ========================= Tiles plugin ===============================-->
<!--
This plugin initialize Tiles definition factory. This later can takes some
parameters explained here after. The plugin first read parameters from
web.xml, thenoverload them with parameters defined here. All parameters
are optional.
The plugin should be declared in each struts-config file.
- definitions-config: (optional)
Specify configuration file names. There can be several comma
separated file names (default: ?? )
- moduleAware: (optional - struts1.1)
Specify if the Tiles definition factory is module aware. If true
(default), there will be one factory for each Struts module.
If false, there will be one common factory for all module. In this
later case, it is still needed to declare one plugin per module.
The factory will be initialized with parameters found in the first
initialized plugin (generally the one associated with the default
module).
true : One factory per module. (default)
false : one single shared factory for all modules
- definitions-parser-validate: (optional)
Specify if xml parser should validate the Tiles configuration file.
true : validate. DTD should be specified in file header (default)
false : no validation

Paths found in Tiles definitions are relative to the main context.
-->
<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin" >
    <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />      
    <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
</plug-in>

<!-- ========================= Validator plugin ================================= -->
<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
    <set-property
        property="pathnames"
        value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml,/WEB-INF/validation.xml"/>
</plug-in>

</struts-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Struts 2, you should mention `type="tiles"` when you return a tile with result tag for an action as follows:

```
    <action name="sampleAction"
        class="com.struts2.SampleAction">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">tile1</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: Added struts_config.xml file